# 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain definition for "Length"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner and have a basic question. I recently added this code to my method

```
    if (dt.Rows.Length > 0)
```

However, I return the error: 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), Im not saying to code this for me (unless you want to :), ) but if someone could point me into the right direction, that would be awesome and good fortune to you. Here is some code to help.

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;

public class Database
{
    private string serverPCICUSTOM, serverPCI;
    private string ConnectionStringPCICUSTOM, ConnectionStringPCI;
    private SqlConnection connectionPCICUSTOM, connectionPCI;
    private string trackingNumber;
    private string soptype;
    private string orderNumber;

         public bool UpdateOrderToShipped(string order)
    {
        orderNumber = order;
        string batch = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessfulOrderBatch"];
        string statement = "UPDATE SOP10100 SET BACHNUMB = '"+ batch +"' WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(statement, connectionPCI);
        comm.Parameters.Add("SOPNUMBE", orderNumber);
        try
        {
            comm.Connection.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            comm.Connection.Close();
            KaplanFTP.errorMsg = "Database error: " + e.Message;
        }

        statement = "SELECT SOPTYPE FROM SOP10100 WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
        comm.CommandText = statement;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Length > 0)      //error here
        {
        comm.Connection.Open();
            soptype = dt.Rows[0]["SOPTYPE"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
        }

            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, so simple!! Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, you can also tick mark my answer and point me up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

use

`if (dt.Rows.count> 0)`

instead of

`if (dt.Rows.length> 0)`

Hope my answer helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388.aspx), not `Length`.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Generally speaking, whenever you have a collection, the property is called `Count` to get the number of items. That's true for many collection types, including DataRowCollection, List, Dictionary, or anything else that implements the [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface (or the non-generic equivalent). That's because the `Count` property comes right from the interface.

The exception to that, is arrays. The number of items in an array can be obtained with `Length`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Count property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

MSDN is your biggest ally here.

[DataRowCollection.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388.aspx)